# white space in filename python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created this small prog to search all PDF's in a directory, determine if they are searchable or not and then move them to the appropriate directory.

I am new to Python and it is probably not the best way but it does work until the file name has White Space in it and I get the following returned.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
>>> os.system("pdffonts.exe " + pdfFile + "> output.txt")
99



import os
import glob
import shutil
directory = os.chdir("C:\MyDir") # Change working directory
fileDir = glob.glob('*.pdf') # Create a list of all PDF's in declared   directory
numFiles = len(fileDir) # Lenght of list
startFile = 0 # Counter variable
seekWord = "TrueType"
while startFile < numFiles:
    pdfFile=fileDir[startFile]
    os.system("pdffonts.exe " + pdfFile + "> output.txt")
    file1output = open("output.txt","r")
    fileContent = file1output.read()
    if seekWord in fileContent:
        shutil.move(pdfFile , "NO_OCR")
    else: shutil.move(pdfFile, "OCR")
    startFile = startFile + 1
```

Comment: Try escaping the quotes around the filename, like `os.system("pdffonts.exe \"" + pdfFile + "\" > output.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system()` uses the shell to execute your command. You'd have to *quote* your filename for the shell to recognise spaces as part of the file, you could do so with the [`shlex.quote()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote):

```
os.system("pdffonts.exe " + shlex.quote(pdfFile) + "> output.txt")
```

However, there is no reason *at all* to use `os.system()` and the shell. You should use the [`subprocess.run()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and configure that to pass back the output without using redirection or a shell:

```
import subprocess

seekWord = b"TrueType"
for pdfFile in fileDir:
    result = subprocess.run(["pdffonts.exe", pdfFile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    fileContent = result.stdout
    if seekWord in fileContent:
        # ...
```

Because `pdfFile` is passed to `pdffonts.exe` *directly* there is no need to worry about a shell parsing and whitespace no longer matters.

Note that I changed `seekWord` to be a `bytes` literal instead as `result.stdout` is a bytes value (no need to try to decode the result to Unicode here).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem doesn't come from python, but the Windows shell. You need to enclose in quotation mark. As I don't have your program pdffonts.exe, I cannot debug. I also made your code more pythonic

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
directory = os.chdir("C:\MyDir") # Change working directory
fileDir = glob.glob('*.pdf') # Create a list of all PDF's in declared   directory

seekWord = "TrueType"
for pdfFile in fileDir:
    os.system('pdffonts.exe "{0}"> output.txt'.format(pdfFile))
    file1output = open("output.txt","r")
    fileContent = file1output.read()
    if seekWord in fileContent:
        shutil.move(pdfFile , "NO_OCR")
    else: 
        shutil.move(pdfFile, "OCR")
```

Comment: What if the filename contains a quote? Those are valid characters in a Windows file path.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your answer is definitely better.

Comment: well I just checked: double quotations don't work in windows file paths, so I don't think it's a problem anyways if there is a single quote in pdfFile.

Comment: Ah, indeed, on Windows [double-quotes are reserved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247), I misremembered.

Comment: Thank you for your help.